# RecyclerView scroll to bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I want to write a Xamarin.UITest that scrolls my RecyclerView to the bottom and taps on the last item in the list. How can I do this?

Comment: Search for `Xamarin RecyclerView scroll to bottom`. Lots of hits. Then attempt to adapt for UITest. If you have trouble, show the code you are adapting, and describe where you are stuck, and what goes wrong.

Comment: I searched for hours and couldn't find a solution. But I figured it out myself and posted it. Not sure why "Xamarin.UI" test was removed from the title - I'm writing a UI test for this, which does not touch the Android SDK. In case there was any confusion...

Comment: And I don't understand why this was voted to be closed. I'm sure someone else out there, who is new to writing Xamarin.UI tests as well, will appreciate this post. I've seen much more simple posts on SO...

Comment: **1)** *"Not sure why "Xamarin.UI" test was removed from the titl"* Because it is listed as a **tag**. Doesn't need to also be in title, so the convention is to remove it from title. Search will correctly find it. **2)** *" I don't understand why this was voted to be closed."* I don't understand either; some voter marked as "needs more focus". Seems like a properly "narrow" question. Unfortunately, StackOverflow lacks a way for voters to say "I disagree; don't close". Don't worry about it. **3)** Thank you for solving it, and posting your answer. You can "accept" your answer after 48 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by setting a view in the last item in my RecyclerView `ContentDescription="isLast"`. Then in my test:

```
app.ScrollDownTo("isLast", "rvId", ScrollStrategy.Gesture, 0.67, 5000, true, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
app.Tap(c => c.Marked("isLast"));
```

Where `rvId` is the ID of the RecyclerView. For example, I have a `TextView` in each item of my RecyclerView, so I set the last one to `MyTextView.ContentDescription="isLast"` in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`